# Calculate Number of Tokens In Text

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have text, for example, `"I sleep at night"` which is of length `l = 4`. I am interested in the sequence of groups of size `s=2` formed from left to right, here: `"I sleep", "sleep at", and "at night"`.

Now, given an arbitrary length `l` and an arbitrary `s <= l`, how do I calculate the number of groups I will get in the end?

Thank you for your help with this simple game!
Feel free to re-tag my question, as I am not sure about the tags.

Comment: Thirds groups are known as $n$-grams. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting some thought into the question, I found the answer myself: The number of groups will be $l+1-s$.